# How to solve easybuild installation problems

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install easybuild on centos 7.9 within a miniconda virtual environment and am running into problems. I installed lmod without problem using conda and then tried to install easybuild using pip as "pip install easybuild". The output is appended below.  Any suggestions as to what to try next?

```
    python -V : Python 3.10.4

    type module
module is a function
module () 
{ 
    local __lmod_my_status;
    local __lmod_sh_dbg;
    if [ -z "${LMOD_SH_DBG_ON+x}" ]; then
        case "$-" in 
            *v*x*)
                __lmod_sh_dbg='vx'
            ;;
            *v*)
                __lmod_sh_dbg='v'
            ;;
            *x*)
                __lmod_sh_dbg='x'
            ;;
        esac;
    fi;
    if [ -n "${__lmod_sh_dbg:-}" ]; then
        set +$__lmod_sh_dbg;
        echo "Shell debugging temporarily silenced: export LMOD_SH_DBG_ON=1 for Lmod's output" 1>&2;
    fi;
    eval "$($LMOD_CMD bash "$@")" && eval $(${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:} -s sh);
    __lmod_my_status=$?;
    if [ -n "${__lmod_sh_dbg:-}" ]; then
        echo "Shell debugging restarted" 1>&2;
        set -$__lmod_sh_dbg;
    fi;
    return $__lmod_my_status
}

    >module --version

Modules based on Lua: Version 8.6.17  2022-03-25 19:53 -05:00
    by Robert McLay mclay@tacc.utexas.edu


module av EasyBuild
No module(s) or extension(s) found!


which -a eb
/data/miniconda/envs/easybuild/bin/eb

eb --version
This is EasyBuild 4.5.3 (framework: 4.5.3, easyblocks: 0.0.UNKNOWN.EASYBLOCKS) on host muon.




       >pip install easybuild
Collecting easybuild
  Using cached easybuild-4.5.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting easybuild-framework==4.5.3
  Using cached easybuild_framework-4.5.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting easybuild-easyblocks==4.5.3
  Using cached easybuild_easyblocks-4.5.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting easybuild-easyconfigs==4.5.3
  Using cached easybuild-easyconfigs-4.5.3.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: easybuild-easyconfigs
  Building wheel for easybuild-easyconfigs (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Installing version 4.5.3 (required versions: API >= 4, easyblocks >= 4.5)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'easybuild/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/__archive__/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/a/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/b/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/c/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/d/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/e/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/f/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/g/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/h/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/i/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/j/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/k/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/l/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/m/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/n/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/o/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/p/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      creating build/lib/easybuild
      creating build/lib/easybuild/easyconfigs
      creating build/lib/easybuild/easyconfigs/p
      error: can't copy 'easybuild/easyconfigs/p/path.py': doesn't exist or not a regular file
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for easybuild-easyconfigs
  Running setup.py clean for easybuild-easyconfigs
Failed to build easybuild-easyconfigs
Installing collected packages: easybuild-framework, easybuild-easyconfigs, easybuild-easyblocks, easybuild
  Running setup.py install for easybuild-easyconfigs ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for easybuild-easyconfigs did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
      Installing version 4.5.3 (required versions: API >= 4, easyblocks >= 4.5)
      running install
      /data/miniconda/envs/easybuild/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'easybuild/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/__archive__/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/a/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/b/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/c/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/d/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/e/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/f/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/g/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/h/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/i/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/j/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/k/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/l/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/m/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/n/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/o/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'easybuild/easyconfigs/p/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      creating build/lib/easybuild
      creating build/lib/easybuild/easyconfigs
      creating build/lib/easybuild/easyconfigs/p
      error: can't copy 'easybuild/easyconfigs/p/path.py': doesn't exist or not a regular file
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> easybuild-easyconfigs

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: When I specified that python==3.9 should be used for the conda virtual environment, the above error message disappeared and the install was successful. On the other hand, the module command does not recognize the easybuild installation, e.g. module load EasyBuild
Lmod has detected the following error:  The following module(s) are unknown: "EasyBuild"

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting a problem caused by a recent change in setuptools 61.0, which was fixed in EasyBuild v4.5.5; see https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild/issues/790 and https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild-easyconfigs/pull/15206 for more details.

So if you try again now, it should work, since you'll pull in EasyBuild v4.5.5 from PyPI (or whatever version is most recent)